# Why the login button is lower than the rest in my Html / Css navbar?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this and it's probably something that I missed some stupid mistake, I don't know ...

When trying to make a simple navbar, with some buttons, I wanted to make this login button to the right separated from the rest but at the same height as the others.
The problem is that this button is a few pixels below, and I don't know where the error is

CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: black;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0mm;
    padding: 0mm;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

li{
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3mm 3mm;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    
}
#is {
    float: right !important;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3mm 3mm;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    
}

li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0.3mm solid red ;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <title> Ejemplo navbar </title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 4</a></li>
                <li id="is"><a href="#">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: because you add extra padding to the li (you already have that padding on your link so you do not need it for the li)

Comment: If you are new to this you probably don't know the `Firefox DevTools` or the `Chrome webdeveloper Tools`. You reach them with a press to `F12`, and they offer a convenient view to find these bugs pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, I just removed the padding top and bottom from the link.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: black;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0mm;
    padding: 0mm;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

li{
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3mm 3mm;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    
}
#is {
    float: right !important;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 3mm;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    
}

li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 0.3mm solid red ;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <title> Ejemplo navbar </title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 4</a></li>
                <li id="is"><a href="#">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have 3mm padding here

```
#is {
    float: right !important;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3mm 3mm;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;   
}
```

The css applies to the `<li>` tag.

However, the padding on the other elements are on the `<a>` tag

```
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3mm 3mm;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;    
}
```

You can either move the padding to `#is a {` or remove the padding from the `#is` and it will look fine

Answer (score 0):

You said that the `a` in the `li` should have a `padding` of 3mm. For the last `li`, the one with `id="is"`, you said it as well. So the text will have the padding of the `a` AND the padding of the `li`, resulting in a top padding of 2 * 3mm.

If you remove the padding of the #is then they are on line.

You can have a fine debug view in the browser when you press `F12`, but you prpbly know this although you are new to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding "3mm 3mm" under id: #is;

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules could me much shorter as it has redundant lines

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: black;
}
ul{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0mm;
    padding: 0mm;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
} 

li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
li:hover {
    border-bottom: 0.3mm solid red ;
}
li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#is {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
       <title> Ejemplo navbar </title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sección 4</a></li>
                <li id="is"><a href="#">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```